# Unexpected identifier in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, oop

I am creating the following object:

```
  var IOBreadcrumb = {
    breadcrumbs: []

    add: function(title, url){
      var crumb = {title, url};
      this.breadcrumbs.push(crumb);
    }
  };
```

I am getting an unexpected identifier error. Not really sure where it is coming from, its in this block of code.

Comment: [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) is your friend.  It will give you line and column numbers of your syntax error.

Comment: @hurrymaplelad No need for an external tool. The browser itself does give you the line number of the error (and other details).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a comma between members of your object, which is the cause of the error you cite. You also need to put a colon, rather than a comma, between the key-value pair in the `crumb` object.

```
var IOBreadcrumb = {
  breadcrumbs: [], // <-- comma here

  add: function(title, url){
    var crumb = {title: url}; // <-- colon here
    this.breadcrumbs.push(crumb);
  }
};
```

If you want an object where there are two members, one the title and one the URL, you may want something like this:

```
var crumb = {
  title: title,
  url: url
};
```

I don't know whether that would work with your `breadcrumbs` setup...

Comment: i would like a crumb to have both a title and a url, not sure how i can represent that as a JSON, or as another data structure?

Comment: should it be `{'title':title,'url':url}` since I want to have a title and a url for a crumb?

Comment: yep: `var crumb = {title: '', url: ''};`

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want this:

```
var IOBreadcrumb = {
    breadcrumbs: [],
    add: function ( title, url ) {
        var crumb = {};
        crumb[ title ] = url;
        this.breadcrumbs.push( crumb );
    }
};
```